# Error while creating a cluster in rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq

I am new to rabbitmq and trying to set up a cluster. However I am getting the following error. The cookie is same in both machine in the `C:\Windows and C:\Users\<user in context>` directories

> rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@node1 Clustering node rabbit@node2
>   with rabbit@node1 ... Error: unable to connect to nodes
>   [rabbit@node1]: nodedown

**DIAGNOSTICS**

> attempted to contact: [rabbit@node1]
>
> rabbit@node1:   * connected to epmd (port 4369) on node1   * epmd
>   reports node 'rabbit' running on port 25672   * TCP connection
>   succeeded but Erlang distribution failed   * suggestion: hostname
>   mismatch?   * suggestion: is the cookie set correctly?   * suggestion:
>   is the Erlang distribution using TLS?
>   current node details:
>   - node name: 'rabbitmq-cli-552@node1'
>   - home dir: C:\Users\dataimports
>   - cookie hash: AWMNITV6TcxGSxvEF6Gndw==

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Looks like erlang cookie is different on the nodes.

Comment: The erlang cookie is the same in all nodes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your rabbit@node2 node is looking for a node named rabbit@node1 when the node that exists is rabbitmq-cli-552@node1.

This happens when rabbitmq is started on install. Best way to get around this is to stop the rabbitmq process (sudo /etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server stop) then to start it (sudo /etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server start).

If the first command fails to stop it, you can always kill the rabbitmq server process, then start it again. The node coming up should have the correct name.