# RabbitMQ Erlang distribution failed

Tags: windows, erlang, rabbitmq, cluster-computing, windows-server-2012-r2

I have two Windows Server 2012 R2 machines located in one of the client's datacenters. Both servers are domain-joined. They both have RabbitMQ 3.6.0. installed on them. RabbitMQ is running as Windows Service on both machines. I've tried to cluster these two machines for a long time now without success. I always get the following error when I try to cluster them.

One the first machine **nodeA** I run the command 'rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@nodeB'. This is what I get:

```
Clustering node 'rabbit@nodeA' with 'rabbit@nodeB' ...
Error: unable to connect to nodes ['rabbit@nodeB']: nodedown

`DIAGNOSTICS`
===========

attempted to contact: ['rabbit@nodeB']

rabbit@nodeB:
 * connected to epmd (port 4369) on nodeB
 * epmd reports node 'rabbit' running on port 25672
 * TCP connection succeeded but Erlang distribution failed
 * suggestion: hostname mismatch?
 * suggestion: is the cookie set correctly?
 * suggestion: is the Erlang distribution using TLS?

current node details:
- node name: 'rabbitmq-cli-3892@nodeA'
- home dir: C:\Users\mydirectory
- cookie hash: l+SSu57+cRyAQ03AJdwAbQ==
```

I've tried this setup with Azure Virtual Machines within Azure Virtual Network and I succeeded to cluster the two VM's, however it seems I cannot connect these two (customer's machines) together.

This is what I have done and ensured:

- There isn't any firewall blocking connections
- Added host names to hosts file located on C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc
- Tried to refer to host names as FQDN without adding anything to hosts file
- Tried to refer to host names with CAPITAL letters and without
- Copied the same exact .erlang.cookie to C:\Windows and C:\Users\mydirectory on both machines.
- I've read, understood and applied RabbitMQ Clustering Guide https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html
- Stopped, restarted, reinstalled RabbitMQ on both machines.

It seems I can't get it to work. On Azure machines, which were not domain-joined clustering worked beautifully.  I am really running out of options... Any help?

Comment: Erlang cookie same on these machines?

Comment: Yes, the cookie is the same and as a result so is the cookie hash

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error while creating a cluster in rabbitmq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34408827/error-while-creating-a-cluster-in-rabbitmq)

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem you need to install rabbitmq as a admin. uninstall then reinstall as admin and it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect to each of RabbitMQ nodes via remote shell and check if value of cookie is the same (cookie can be set in 3 different ways: .erlang.cookie is one of them).

```
erl -remsh 'rabbitmq-cli-3892@nodeA' -name 'test@nodeA'
erlang:get_cookie().
```

Comment: Hi, I get value _nocookie_ on both machines. This is odd.. when I try join_cluster I see cookie hash that is identical... (see my previous post)